# App Submission: Where do I put my EULA (End User License Agreement)?

Tags: app-store-connect

My video chat app submission recently got rejected, and these are the reasons they listed:

> We encourage you to review your app concept and remove the functionality that randomly connects users. Users must be identifiable with a profile and have the ability to initiate and accept chat requests from other users. It is also necessary that you put all of the following precautions in place:
>
> - Require that users agree to terms (EULA); these terms must make it clear that there is no tolerance for objectionable content or abusive users
> - A method for filtering objectionable content
> - A mechanism for users to flag objectionable content
> - A mechanism for users to block abusive users
> - The developer must act on objectionable content reports within 24 hours by removing the content and ejecting the user who provided the offending content

My question is, I thought every app uses Apple's EULA by default, so what is the first stipulation about (or is that just a reminder?)?

[image]

I downloaded a similar app called Cha Cha, which doesn't force the user to "Agree" to the EULA, I also downloaded another app called Cake, which does have the EULA when you sign up.

Should setting it to Apple's EULA good enough? If not, would putting a link to it in the description suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you choose the Custom EULA option on iTunes Connect, you can submit an EULA to a new field shown for the app on iTunes Connect, which is then shown under a separate button on the App Store product page.

Comment: Is this required? Or can I just use Apple's?

Comment: @Edmund When you implement features Apple's EULA doesn't cover, you'll need to add your own. For Apple to tell you that you need to provide an EULA, it's very likely this is the case.

Comment: ooo thanks! So is setting it in iTunes Connect good enough? Or do I need to show it in app?

Comment: @Edmund I've never included an EULA in my actual app (only on iTunes Connect), but then I've never been rejected with the reason you have! It seems like you're doing some pretty strange things with the ‘randomly connecting users’ that Apple might not really like, in which case an EULA inside the app might be required. I'm not certain.

Comment: Yeh I eventually added a sign up flow so that people have "profiles". Thanks I'll try just setting it in itunes connect

Comment: @Edmund Let me know how it goes, I'd be interested to see what they say!

Comment: Yes, I'd also appreciate seeing how you go. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

I see the answers that have been submitted and I wanted to submit my own as I've had a different experience.

You have to change the custom EULA in iTunes Connect, but that is not enough. Below is my conversation with Apple after changing the custom EULA and having my app rejected again.

> I modified the standard Apple EULA in ITunes Connect which can be found when you download the app on iTunes. It’s not in the app as a pop up as it’s in the App Store as a download. I can add it to the app as a pop up, but from my research the iTunes connect EULA applied is all that matters. Is this not true?

Their response:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for your response. To answer your specific question, EULA agreement must be part of the registration workflow and available from within the app on demand after login.
>
> We look forward to reviewing your app once these issues have been addressed.

Therefore, I'm going to add the EULA to the user registration and make it available "On Demand"